# Sample a list of dataframes in R

Tags: r, list, dataframe, lapply, sample

I have a list composed of 16 dataframes (`dientes`). I would like to sample 80% of the rows with no replacement in each dataframe. I tried with these `lapply()` functions with no success:

```
index <- lapply(1:nrow(dientes), sample, round(0.8*nrow), replace = F)
index <- lapply(dientes, sample, round(0.8*nrow), replace = F)
```

Where am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do the following:

```
index <- lapply(dientes, function(x){x[sample(x, round(0.8*nrow(x)), replace = F),]})
```

lapply takes the list `dientes` as input

`function(x){..}` applies the operation you want to each element

`x` is each element and you take rows from it with `x[sample(...),]`

Answer (score 2):

If `index` should contain the list of sampled data.frames, you could do this:

```r
## mock list of data.frames
dientes <- list(A=mtcars, B=iris, C=volcano)

## count input rows
lapply(dientes, nrow)
#> $A
#> [1] 32
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 150
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 87

index <- lapply(dientes, function(x) x[sample(nrow(x), round(0.8*nrow(x))), ])

## count output rows
lapply(index, nrow)
#> $A
#> [1] 26
#> 
#> $B
#> [1] 120
#> 
#> $C
#> [1] 70
```

<sup>Created on 2020-03-18 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>